# How to display field collection items left to right in views grid

Tags: views

I created a content type as follows:

Content Type > field collection field > accepts unlimited values.
Field collection field > text field, Image field. > Each accepts one value.

Add content > content type x > added 5 field collection items. So I have one content with 5 field collection items. Each item has one text field value and one image value.

Views:
Created views grid > number of columns equal to 3.
Fields > added field collection field.

[image: Views]

I see all the items in a single column. I would like to display items left to right. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `Content: MyProducts` (within fields).

Then scroll down a bit, until you see `MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS`, click on it to expand it and then uncheck the `Display all items in the same row` box.

[image]